# Passing KeyEvent to a different component

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

I am trying to allow for a JTextArea to have focus but if the user enters keyboard input and control is not pressed then to forward that key event on to the command JTextField.

I tried to simply append the key char to the text in the JTextField but that results in unknown characters when pressing anything except letters, symbols, or numbers.

```java
newField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(!e.isControlDown()) {
                    Console.consoleWindow.appendTextToCMD(e.getKeyChar());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use processEvent on your other JComponent. Also, you need to create a new AWTEvent - copy all fields but with the source being the new JComponent